# Object.entries/Object.values is undefined with Babel-polyfill in IE 11

Tags: webpack, babeljs, babel-polyfill

To optimize page load time our my app, I split the bundle into two bundles: `webpack-bundle` (this contains my code) and `vendor-bundle` (this contains everything in node modules). But I am starting to get several errors when my users visit my website from Internet Explorer. They get errors like "includes" is undefined and "Object.entries"/"Object.values" are undefined. Clearly, I need to include `babel-polyfill` and load that before my other bundles. But I am not sure how to do it when my entry is an object.

This is the old entry. It is an array (before I split the bundle):

```
const config = {
  "entry": [
    "es5-shim/es5-shim", 
    "es5-shim/es5-sham",
    "url-search-params-polyfill",   
    "@babel/polyfill",  
    "./app/registration"    
  ],
```

This is my current `webpack.config` where I changed my entry to an object and used `splitChunks`. This will out put two bundles.

```
const config = {
  "entry": {
    "webpack-bundle": "./app/registration"
  },

  "output": {
    filename: "[name].js",
    path: pathLib.resolve(__dirname, "../app/assets/webpack"),
  },

  "module": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "test": /\.(svg)$/,
        "use": [
          {
            "loader": "url-loader",
            "options": {"limit": 8192}
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "test": /\.css$/,
        "use": [
          "style-loader",
          "css-loader"
        ]
      },
      {
        "test": require.resolve("react"),
        "use": {
          "loader": "imports-loader",
          "options": {
            "sham": "es5-shim/es5-sham",
            "shim": "es5-shim/es5-shim"
          }
        },
      },
      {
        "exclude": /node_modules/,
        "test": /\.jsx?$/,
        "use": {
          "loader": "babel-loader",
          "options": {
            "plugins": [
              "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
              ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", {"legacy": true}],
              "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from",
              "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent",
              "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings",
              "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator",
              "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
              "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions",
              "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
              "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta",
              "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx"
            ],
            "presets": [
              "@babel/preset-env",
              "@babel/preset-react"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
  },

  "plugins": [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      "$": "jquery",
      "jQuery": "jquery",
      "window.jQuery": "jquery"
    }),
    new UglifyJsPlugin()
  ],

  "optimization": {
    "splitChunks": {
      "cacheGroups": {
        "vendor": {
          "test": /node_modules/,
          "chunks": "all",
          "name": "vendor-bundle"
        }
      }
    }
  },

  "resolve": {
    "alias": {
      "Lib": pathLib.resolve(__dirname, "app/lib/"),
      "Shared": pathLib.resolve(__dirname, "app/shared/")
    },
    "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

babelrc

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", {"legacy": true}],
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx",
   [ "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", {"regenerator": true}]
  ],
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}
```

I tried to re-write entry this way, but it didn't work:

```
 "entry": {
    "polyfill-bundle": "@babel/polyfill",
    "es5-shim-bundle": "es5-shim/es5-shim",
    "es5-sham-bundle": "es5-shim/es5-sham",
    "webpack-bundle": "./app/registration"
  },
```

1. How can I make sure that `babel/polyfill` is loaded and is compiling correctly? Should I add it in the entry, or ProvidePlugin?
2. Shouldn't `babel/polyfill` be included in `vendor-bundle` already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to replace babel-polyfill with this core-js.
Install core-js, create a .babelrc file and place it in it.

**.babelrc**

```
{
 "presets": [
    [
     "@babel/preset-env",
     {
      "useBuiltIns": "usage",
      "corejs": 3
     }
   ],
   "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}
```

**webpack.conf.js**

```js
const config = {
  "entry": {
    "webpack-bundle": "./app/registration"
  },

  "output": {
    filename: "[name].js",
    path: pathLib.resolve(__dirname, "../app/assets/webpack"),
  },

  "module": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "test": /\.jsx?$/,
        "exclude": /node_modules/,
        "use": {
          "loader": "babel-loader",
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "test": /\.css$/,
        "use": [
          "style-loader",
          "css-loader"
        ]
      },
      {
        "test": /\.(svg)$/,
        "use": [{
          "loader": "url-loader",
          "options": {
            "limit": 8192
          }
        }]
      },
    ],
  },

  "plugins": [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      "$": "jquery",
      "jQuery": "jquery",
      "window.jQuery": "jquery"
    }),
    new UglifyJsPlugin()
  ],

  "optimization": {
    "splitChunks": {
      "cacheGroups": {
        "vendor": {
          "test": /node_modules/,
          "chunks": "all",
          "name": "vendor-bundle"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "resolve": {
    "alias": {
      "Lib": pathLib.resolve(__dirname, "app/lib/"),
      "Shared": pathLib.resolve(__dirname, "app/shared/")
    },
    "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

**package.jon**

```
"browserslist": [
  "last 2 version",
  "> 1%",
  "not dead"
],
```

The above entry will add polyfills to browsers including ie10 and ie11. To check this, add `debug: true`. The console will display exactly what has been added, what files, etc.

```
{
  debug: true,
  "useBuiltIns": "usage",
  "corejs": 3
}
```

More [browserl](https://browserl.ist/) and [github](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist)

Comment: I installed `core-js`, imported it in the entry file and my app is working in IE even though I did not specify "corejs: 3" in my ".babelrc". Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Trying adding `babel-polyfill` to your entry like so and here's the link to the [docs](https://new.babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill.html).

```
const config = {
  "entry": {
    "webpack-bundle": ["babel-polyfill","./app/registration"]
  },
...
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! I tried but I am still getting errors, especially when I tried to visit my website from IE version 11.

Comment: Another possible solution is to have `import 'babel-polyfill';` in your entry, instead of webpack.

Comment: I was not able to access my website through IE, but adding "@babel/polyfill" to the beginning of the entry array definitely got rid of a lot of the errors I received. Thank you so much!

Comment: @babel/polyfill is deprecated with [Babel 7.4.0](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill)